# How to Design ADS so as only Selected Computer Names can join the domain

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am wondering weather someone can help me out for two most critical scenario from security point of view.

1) First can we design a ADS in Domain such that only selected and predefined computer name  can join the domains. all other computer name should not be allowed to join Domain irrespective of users rights.

2) Secondly if at all somehow (  By mistake or intentionally ) computer name other than predefined name could able to join the domains, then in that case after logon to domain, user should get pop up warning to change the computer name to its original predefined name,  otherwise he should not be allowed to use the ADS resources..

Can anyone has implemented such kind of solutions. If yes,then kindly suggest me steps and configurations needed for the same...

Thanking you
regards

Comment: Welcoming kindly your thankful regards, what is reason for decision to restriction for join the domains by predefined name only?

Answer (score 1):

In Group Policy, there is a setting under `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment` called "Add workstations to domain."

By default, it is set to `Authenticated Users` (i.e. anyone with a valid username and password).

As you have observed, in many environments, allowing *anyone* to add devices to the domain will have undesirable consequences, including both inconsistent naming and unauthorized devices.

If you wish to limit the ability to join workstations to the domain, consider assigning this user right to a specified group consisting of appropriate administrators and/or managers.

Comment: Many Thanks for replying promptly. The reason for this is to to maintain consistency nomenclature of computer names.Its important for me just because I am working in environment where even Junior IT support engineer to which joining to domain work is delegated  doesn't bother to maintain consistence computer name policy. So I don't want to depend on the them and willing the above type of scenario in which either computer name other than predefined wont be able to join at all of if he can then he won't be able to access ADS resources.

Comment: You can not fix a legal and social prolblem (employees ignoring their legal obligations to follow orders and established procedures) that is accepted by the company by some technological solution when the technology is built on the concept of the users being sensible. THe solution to your problem is to have HR talk to those people and make sure they understand they PAY for the fix for their ignorance of established procedures in the future.